# Is there any way for me to create an image source that contains variables

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image source that alters depending on the user's input, however the following line of code does not seem to be working:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + document.getElementById("lat").value+ "," + document.getElementById("lat").value + "&zoom=20&size=600x300&maptype=satellite&key=AIzaSyCmDRHVBQ-YwI1BMa0j5ZUvoXTZCUKeoYM"/>
```

This line follows the function:

```
function pos() {

    alert("Your chosen coordinates are: (" + 
        document.getElementById("lat").value + ", " 
        +document.getElementById("long").value + ")");

    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
    var long = parseFloat(document.getElementById("long").value);
}
```

Could anyone provide any help on how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: You can't embed a map inside of an image tag.

Comment: and the string concatenation is not happening like this